# File keeps re-opening by itself

Tags: excel, vba

Hello One of the VP where I work made a workbook that has the below macro in it. For some reason after I open the file and close it on my own the file re-opens itself every so often. Is this because the timer in the workbook is set to reset its closing process?  I am not very well versed in VBA yet so that may not be even close to what the Sub Reset is doing.  Note this apparently only happens to me and not anyone else and we have no idea why. only VBA experience I have is like making workbooks that don't close as pranks or making time stamps or color counting formulas.

```
Dim xTime As String
Dim xWB As Workbook
 
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
'Updated by Extendoffice 2019/1/20
    On Error Resume Next
    xTime = "00:30:00"
    Set xWB = ActiveWorkbook
    If xTime = "" Then Exit Sub
    Reset
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    On Error Resume Next
    If xTime = "00:30:00" Then Exit Sub
    Reset
End Sub
 
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    If xTime = "" Then Exit Sub
    Reset
End Sub
 
Sub Reset()
    Static xCloseTime
    If xCloseTime <> 0 Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Application.OnTime xCloseTime, "SaveWork1", , False
    End If
    xCloseTime = Now + TimeValue(xTime)
    ActiveWorkbook.Application.OnTime xCloseTime, "SaveWork1", , True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timer is a async process so it will keep running in background
you can reset it on closing of the workbook.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Reset
End Sub
```

Comment: At which point in the code would I place that sub? Just wanting to make sure I put it in the correct location of the process if that matters. As I said I am still new to VBA so I am not sure if I can enter that at the end or if it needs to be in a specific step.

Comment: Does not matter where you put it. to help you: put it after the Workbook_Open method

Comment: I just realize it kicks of a new OnTime in the Reset method. you might need to change the code a bit: The BeforeClose needs to be enhanced. Let me know if you need some more help on this

Answer (score 0):

The workbook is being reopened when `Application.OnTime` calls the `SaveWork1` that is attached to it.  `Static xCloseTime` is storing the time that the `SaveWork1` is scheduled to be ran.  The time is being stored so that the `Application.OnTime` event can be cancelled.

I believe that you are the only one being affected because you are the only one that dabbles in VBA.  VBA errors may cause Static variables to lose their values.  When `Static xCloseTime` the `SaveWork1` is rescheduled.